# Why my element fails to be centered only in small resolution in Tailwind css?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have an element as such :

```
  <div className= 'place-self-center md:col-start-2 md:col-end-2 p-2'>
```

According to the documentation place-self-center is the default and if it is not `md` it should be triggered. However this is present all the time on the element.

```
 <div className= 'sm:place-self-center md:col-start-2 md:col-end-2 p-2'>
```

also gives me the same results.

How can I make sure the element is center only on mobile view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Tailwind uses a mobile first breakpoint system, similar to what you might be used to in other frameworks like Bootstrap.

Use unprefixed utilities to target mobile, and override them at larger breakpoints.
you must `use place-self-center` like this code:

```
<div class="place-self-center md:place-self-start lg:place-self-start">2</div>
```